# Is the direct limit of a system of null-homotopic inclusions weakly contractible?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, geometric-topology

Suppose we are given a directed system of spaces:

$$ ... \to A_n \xrightarrow{f_n} A_{n+1} \xrightarrow{f_{n+1}}A_{n+2} \to ...$$

such that for every $n$, there is some $m > n$ for which the composite $A_n \xrightarrow{f_{m-n}} A_m$ is null-homotopic (writing $f_{m-n}$ for the composite $f_{m-1}f_{m-2}...f_n$).

Is it then true that the space $A = \varinjlim_n A_n$ obtained as the direct limit of this system must be weakly contractible?

I am still trying to build intuition for how much information one can obtain on a direct limit from its constituent spaces, so I apologize if the question is a bit simple-minded.

Comment: I think you will need to take care with your categories and definitions. The direct limit of a sequence of arbitrary spaces is notoriously badly-behaved, and I would guess that there are problematic examples even when all the maps $f_n$ are null-homotopic. If you work in a convenient category and consider instead the homotopy direct limit, then the answer to your question is true.

Comment: I do have a specific instance in mind which is particularly well-behaved. Namely, the sequence of Stiefel manifolds of $n$-frames in $\mathbb{R}^k$ under inclusion maps, indexed over $k$. In this scenario, the inclusion map from degree $k$ to degree $2k$ is null-homotopic.

Answer (score 1):

I share Tyrone's doubts concerning the general case. Although I do know that much about Stiefel manifolds, I believe the corresponding direct limit has trivial homotopy groups. The Stiefel manifolds can be given the structure of CW-complexes, and I think the inclusions are cellular (you should check this).

Now, given a direct system of CW-complexes $A_n$ and cellular inclusions $f_n : A_n \to A_{n+1}$, the direct limit $A$ will also be a CW-complex. For any map $\phi : S^k \to A$ the image $\phi(S^k)$ is contained in a finite subcomplex of $A$ and therefore in some $A_n$. Hence $\phi = i_n \circ \phi_n$ for some map $\phi_n : S^k \to A_n$. But if the "null-homotopy-condition" is satisfied, we can conclude that $\phi$ must be inessential.